# SQL Server: Case with the statement "NOT IN"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to do a `CASE` statement in SQL Server (stored procedure) where I am supposed to check if whether or not it should get some results from another table.

I just made this up to illustrate the example (not working!)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cards
WHERE
    CardID = @CardID
    AND
    CardID = 
        CASE WHEN @AlreadyOnDeck = 1 THEN
            IN (
                    SELECT CardID FROM OnDeckTable WHERE CardID = @CardID
            )
        CASE WHEN @AlreadyOnDeck = 0 THEN
            NOT IN (
                    SELECT CardID FROM OnDeckTable WHERE CardID = @CardID
            )
        END
```

I need to make the case `IN` / `NOT IN` depending on `@AlreadyOnDeck` variable

Comment: You want to dynamically generate a part of sql statement that should contain IN if @AlreadyOnDeck is 1 and NOT IN if 0?

Comment: IIRC you can't populate IN by getting values using a SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Max's answer but uses CASE statements. (May produce a slightly better execution plan due to short circuiting of the outer CASE statement.)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cards c
WHERE
    c.CardID = @CardID
    AND
    1 = (CASE WHEN @AlreadyOnDeck = 1 THEN 
                   (CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * OnDeckTable dt where dt.CardID = c.CardID) THEN 1 END)
              WHEN @AlreadyOnDeck = 0 THEN 
                   (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(select * from OnDeckTable dt where dt.CardID = c.CardID) THEN 1 END)       
        END)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work, but haven't tested (no test data provided).

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cards
WHERE
    CardID = @CardID
    AND
    (
        exists (select 1 from OnDeckTable where CardId = @CardId and @AlreadyOnDeck = 1)
        or not exists (select 1 from OnDeckTable where CardId = @CardId and @AlreadyOnDeck = 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cards crd
WHERE
    CardID = @CardID
    AND
    (
    (@AlreadyOnDeck = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OnDeckTable dt WHERE dt.CardID = crd.CardID))
    OR
    (@AlreadyOnDeck = 0 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OnDeckTable dt WHERE dt.CardID = crd.CardID))
    )
```

Comment: I think @DerekKromm's answer also works and is very similar to this one. though, the sentence organization has more sense and readability in this answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have added +1 to @DerekKromm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a join like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM cards c
LEFT JOIN OnDeckTable o ON c.CardID = o.CardID
WHERE c.CardID = @CardID
  AND (((@alreadyOnDeck = 0) AND (o.CardID is not null)) OR
      ((@alreadyOnDeck = 1) AND (o.CardID is null)))
```

I believe this will be faster than the sub-query exists suggestions but I have not tested.

Also note, I did not test the code above, it may have typos.

The fastest way to solve this is to encase in one if statement for the @alreadyOnDeck variable, like this:

```
if (@alreadyOnDeck = 1)
  -- select for this case
else
  -- select for this case.
```

If your code is in a stored procedure this would be fastest way, the input is not going to change during the query.